# npm install -g gulpjs/gulp.git#4.0 fails

Tags: git, gulp

I have installed `git`, `node.js v4.1.0` and `npm v3.3.3`
I open a cmd as administrator
And I try to install also gulp by running `npm install -g gulpjs/gulp.git#4.0`

I get the following error

> Ssh:connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out.

I tried to configure the git by trying
`git config --global url."https://".` instead of `git://`

But still I get the same error.

Can please anyone help me,
Thank you in advance
Christos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you cannot access through your network the address you want.

Check your proxy and anything else that may be blocking you, the problem seems to be of network nature.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem. Although that I had configured the proxy in my gitconfig I couldn't clone that repository. I tried bypass the proxy and it worked. Thanks alot